# World Clock in gnome-shell

Tags: gnome-shell, clock, gnome-shell-extension

Is there any shell extension which will enable Ubuntu 11.10 gnome-shell 
users to view time at different locations ?

Answer (score 2):

There is one planned that will possibly also have weather as well, but it is still being worked on at the moment :-)

http://mail.gnome.org/archives/gnome-shell-list/2012-January/msg00006.html

http://mail.gnome.org/archives/gnome-shell-list/2012-February/msg00075.html

---

See this for later releases: [Clocks for multiple timezones in GNOME Shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144895/clocks-for-multiple-timezones-in-gnome-shell)

Comment: could you add a link to your answer to who is doing this work?

Comment: I do really miss that ! There is one Binary Clock extension which is not of much use for ordinary user.

Comment: hmmmm sorry i read it in passing in the gnome-shell mailing list. http://mail.gnome.org/archives/gnome-shell-list/2012-January/date.html

Comment: There is now gnome-clocks http://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-clocks/ which is also available via synaptic and ubuntu software center if your on ubuntu 12.10 :-) and some more information may be found here http://worldofgnome.org/first-look-at-gnome-clocks/