# Clocks for multiple timezones in GNOME Shell

Tags: gnome-shell, time, clock, timezone

I looked everywhere but I couldn't find a way to display multiple clocks in GNOME 3. In classic GNOME and Unity, it is possible. Also, for some strange reason, additional timezones cannot be added to the clock using the time-date applet in classic GNOME. Any solutions?

Comment: Isn't there a world clock app in software center?

Comment: There are apps but nothing that can be viewed in a glance, you know.

Comment: This should be a generic question with different answers for each Ubuntu version, IMHO.

Answer (score 57):

To install multiple clocks, you need [GNOME Clocks](https://snapcraft.io/gnome-clocks) which is now available in the official repos and you can install via Ubuntu Software (formerly the Software Center).

(**Note:** The button above points to the snap store, which does have GNOME Clocks, but the snap application doesn't fully work on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS; the times don't show up.)

Or, to install it from the command line:

1. Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>)
2. Run

   ```
   sudo apt install gnome-clocks
   ```

**Logout and login** after installing and it will appear in your notification menu. Or instead of logging out and in, restart GNOME Shell: press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `r`, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: +1 but OP looks for 12.04, which is still valid distro at the moment. I tried to install on Precise but the dependency isn't satisfied.

Comment: This also works in 17.10!

Comment: works on 18.04 as well

Comment: they show up in the clock notification menu once you log out and back in again. Note that the snap version doesn't seem to have that functionality; stick to the apt-installed package.

Comment: This works in Ubuntu 23.10

Comment: This also adds a search provider, so you can search for "Kolkata" in GNOME's search, and it will display the current time in Kolkata.

Answer (score 22):

I found [gnome-clocks](https://launchpad.net/gnome-clocks/) on Launchpad. It can be installed with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-clocks
```

As of 18.04 LTS. It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Can confirm this works with Ubuntu 20.04 (focal)

Answer (score 10):

Today there is **MultiClock**, a Gnome 3 Extension that puts another clock into your bar.

Really useful and allow multiple timezones.

- https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/605/multiclock/
- Source: https://github.com/mibus/MultiClock

Only drawback is you need to know how to edit JavaScript for its configuration:

```
gedit ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/MultiClock@mibus.org/extension.js
```

But it's not hard. In the file change the following variables according to your timezone parameters

```
const Timezones = {
    'GMT',
    'Australia/Adelaide',
    'Australia/Perth',
    'America/Denver',

};
```

NOTE: Must use formatting found in TZ Database Time Zones!
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Comment: I think the correct file which has the `Timezones` entries is [`extension.js`](https://github.com/mibus/MultiClock/blob/master/extension.js), *not* [`metadata.json`](https://github.com/mibus/MultiClock/blob/master/metadata.json). I have made an edit accordingly. Please check and reply.

Comment: This extension sounds great but I got errors when editing the list and can't use it anymore. Had to move to something else.

Answer (score 8):

This [GNOME extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) called [**Top Bar Clocks**](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1479/top-bar-clocks/) lets the user add multiple clocks to the top bar.
[image]

Another extension, called [**Timezones extension**](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2657/timezones-extension/) does something similar.
[image]

Comment: This combined within installing gnome-clocks did exactly what I wanted.  I added the clocks in the Gnome Clocks application and after a reboot top get the plugin working they were visible in the top bar.

Answer (score 4):

[Timezone](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1060/timezone/) is a beautiful **GNOME extension** to see people with their timezones. For more info see [the Github page](https://github.com/jwendell/gnome-shell-extension-timezone).

[image: screenshot]

1. **Install** the extension (when your GNOME Shell is ready for it)
2. **Create** a text-file with the name **`people.json`** (*example code see below)
3. **Place** the file where you like.
4. **Edit the settings** of the extensions in Ubuntu Tweak or directly on the [extension-page](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1060/timezone/) when you have the [Firefox Gnome extension add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gnome-shell-integration/) and set where the json-file is placed, e.g. `file:///home/USERNAME/people.json`.
5. **Logout** & login or Alt-F2 with command `r` (or maybe a restart is needed)

*Example code for people.json:

```
[
  {
    "name": "California",
    "avatar": "file:///home/USERNAME/Pictures/California.JPG",
    "city": "Los Angeles",
    "tz": "America/Los_Angeles"
  },
  {
    "name": "Hans Pacquiao",
    "avatar": "file:///home/cds/Pictures/Hans.JPG",
    "city": "Indiana",
    "tz": "America/Indiana/Knox"
  },
  {
   "name": "Samar friends",
   "avatar": "file:///home/USERNAME/Pictures/Samarfriends.ico",
   "city": "Philippines",
   "tz": "Asia/Manila"
  }
]
```

For more time zones information, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Comment: I love this idea for an extension!

Answer (score 2):

I use [FoxClocks](https://foxclocks.org/), which is an add-on for Firefox ([here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/foxclocks/)) or Chrome ([here](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/foxclocks/obcbigljfpgappaaofailjjoabiikckk?pli=1)).

While it is not an extension for Unity or GNOME, I normally have Firefox open anyhow.

Comment: If we're talking stuff that runs in the browser, I might add the [Personal World Clock](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/personal.html) from timeanddate.com.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the clock applet from the Screenlets? You can have multiple clocks set to different time zones.
You can install screenlet by doing sudo apt-get install screenlets in terminal.

You can add/remove individual clocks. And set individual/all clocks to autostart at login.

Comment: I've used screenlets before. They are not really stable. I would prefer having something integrated with the Gnome clock (or atleast that is on the panel). An extension perhaps.

Comment: Ok. It looks like the work is in progress. You can see the mockup here http://justinstories.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/ready-for-gnome-3-2-world-clock-comes-to-gnome-shell/

Answer (score 0):

An extension that puts different clocks directly on the top bar is [Panel Work Clock Lite](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/946/panel-world-clock-lite/). It appears to be well maintained as of the writing of this answer.