# Ubuntu 19.10 Multiple Timezone clocks

Tags: 17.10, gnome-shell, 19.10, clock, timezone

How do I add multiple clocks with different time zones in Ubuntu 19.10.

**Solution:**

- Install clock using `sudo apt install gnome-clocks`
- Open `Clock` app and add required timezones
- Restart the PC

**Important**: Do not install using snap or using software installer, this have permission issue to clock and multiple timezones won't appear.

Ref: [How to get world clocks to show on the task bar in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070718/how-to-get-world-clocks-to-show-on-the-task-bar-in-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: See this answer in particular: https://askubuntu.com/a/436474/480481 You can install `gnome-clocks` by running `sudo apt install gnome-clocks`.

Comment: I used to add multiple clocks as described in this link. All these settings gone? Only option is to add app? 
https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/how-to-display-time-from-multiple-cities-in-ubuntu/

Comment: Tip from the link is not working because Ubuntu 17.10 is shipped with GNOME shell **instead of** Unity like before. It's like a new world! Of course I cannot claim it's the *only* solution, but it's an easy and kinda "*official*" solution.

Comment: Got it... Thanks for the information... I just tried, unfortunately it doesn't  have any quick access from top bar. I have to open the app every time to see the time for other timezones :-( Am I missing something? May be I should try different clock.

Comment: You don't have to open the app to see the times, if you click on the clock indicator or press <super>+<m> the drop-down tray will open there it should list all the times from different zones, something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9Awk.png

Answer (score 32, accepted):

See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/436474/480481) to my proposed duplicate. You can achieve this using `gnome-clocks`.

To install it open Terminal and run

```
sudo apt install gnome-clocks
```

Once installed,

1. Search for "*Clocks*" in *Activities* overview and launch it.
2. Set a new world clock (or clocks) by clicking on "*New*".
3. Logout and login again.

You should see the added clock(s) in the drop-down dialogue after clicking on the clock in the top bar. Alternatively you may press <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> to open/close the dialogue.

Comment: great! after restarting I can see new time zones. I didn't do the step 3 earlier.

Comment: worked perfectly in Ubuntu 20.04, I didn't even have to login again.