# How to get world clocks to show on the task bar in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, clock, gnome-clocks

I make extensive use of the multiple timezone clock feature in 16.04.

After upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04 I found various guides that installing GNOME Clocks and adding time zones I should see them in the dropdown when I click the clock on the taskbar.

However it isn't showing up in there, despite restarting a few times.

I also installed GNOME Weather and its section shows now in the clock dropdown.

Has anyone else had this problem? Ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Good question. Maybe some GNOME Extension exists. FYI on MATE it is native and nice looking - https://i.stack.imgur.com/4a8nv.png .

Answer (score 63):

GNOME Clocks should work fine if it's [set up correctly](https://askubuntu.com/a/969135/480481). However, if you have installed the application from the *(GNOME) Software* application, there is a chance that you have installed the [snap](https://docs.snapcraft.io/snaps/intro) version of Clocks. You can verify that by running `snap list` and checking whether the output contains `gnome-clocks`.

If that is the case, this behaviour is not very surprising given the security restrictions of snap packages. To fix this remove the snap application by running

```
snap remove gnome-clocks
```

and install the traditional one by running

```
sudo apt install gnome-clocks
```

Then you should be able to find added time zones in the date & time dropdown tray (*N.B. You may have to log out and back in*).

[image]

Comment: Doesn't show up. The `World Clocks` section is not there.

Comment: @BishwasMishra Try logout and login again.

Comment: I think you're right @karel. This is mentioned in the [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/969135/480481) I wrote previously, where OP [confirms that relogin is required](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969069/ubuntu-17-10-multiple-timezone-clocks/969135#comment1552632_969135).

Comment: They also show up after a reload of Gnome (without needing to log out/in): Alt + F2, type "r" (without quotes), and Enter

Comment: This works for Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Worked for me without relogging or restarting Gnome. It just showed right up after installation.

Comment: Also works perfectly in Pop!_OS 22.04 without having to reload gnome.

Answer (score 13):

@pomsky answer (replacing snap package with apt package) works for me as well. In addition, I also like to use gnome extension **panel-world-clock-lite** to make it always visible on the task bar:

[image]

EDIT:

To install it:

1. Install Gnome Clocks and Gnome Tweak Tool

   sudo apt install gnome-clocks

   sudo apt-add-repository universe

   sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
2. Install [panel-world-clock-lite](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/946/panel-world-clock-lite/)
3. Open Gnome Clocks and add timezones to be shown
4. Open Gnome Tweak and enable "Panel World Clock" extension
5. Reboot your computer

Comment: Seems super cool. Do you have references on how to install this on top of Gnome's clocks? Wasn't able to find it in snap/apt stores for ubuntu.

Comment: @Naz, (1) install Gnome clocks via apt-get, (2) install Gnome tweaks, (3) enable extension "Panel world clock (lite)"

Comment: Got an error and rebooted the pc and it worked!

Comment: Works great!  If you get an error just log out and back in.